# MDM check in request is not received on the server

Tags: ios, ssl, mdm

I have followed the MDM protocol to define the following steps:

1) Create a .p12 certificate which contains the server address. this certificate was used in the .mobileconfig file.

2) The server was signed by a custom CA certificate, which was installed on the device before installing the .mobileconfig.

3) The server is listening to HTTP Put message.

What is happening:
The device installs successfully the CA certificate, then installs the profile (.mobileconfig) from the same MDM server (thus the https handshake is successfull, at least from safari).

After the installation, I expect to receive an https PUT message for the checkin request by the device, yet this request is not received.

I have attached the device logs:

```
Jan  1 13:50:43 iPad-minQA profiled[116] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Profile “com.apple.mgmt.External.MV9BR98H24” queued for installation.
Jan  1 13:50:43 iPad-minQA Preferences[272] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Jan  1 13:50:43 iPad-minQA Preferences[272] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Jan  1 13:50:44 iPad-minQA assertiond[67] <Error>: assertion failed: 13G35: assertiond + 30600 [0B862A7D-6E8B-3778-AD17-C7694ECD5BCD]: 0x16
Jan  1 13:50:44 iPad-minQA Unknown[67] <Error>: 
Jan  1 13:50:45 iPad-minQA profiled[116] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Checking for MDM installation...
Jan  1 13:50:45 iPad-minQA profiled[116] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: ...finished checking for MDM installation.
Jan  1 13:50:48 iPad-minQA profiled[116] <Error>: MKBGetDeviceConfigurations: aks_get_configuration result: 0
Jan  1 13:50:48 iPad-minQA profiled[116] <Error>: MKBGetDeviceConfigurations: aks_get_configuration result: 0
Jan  1 13:50:48 iPad-minQA SpringBoard[58] <Warning>: throwing out icon because it isn't visible in the model : node=<SBApplicationIcon: 0x14d774540; nodeID: "com.apple.facetime"> com.apple.facetime
Jan  1 13:50:48 iPad-minQA SpringBoard[58] <Warning>: throwing out icon because it isn't visible in the model : node=<SBApplicationIcon: 0x14d7645c0; nodeID: "com.apple.camera"> com.apple.camera
Jan  1 13:50:48 iPad-minQA keybagd[45] <Error>: 0x16e1bb000 KBUpdateKeyBag: Saved new keybag with result 0
Jan  1 13:50:48 iPad-minQA SpringBoard[58] <Warning>: ===^^^ WE WILL UPDATE ZKW!
Jan  1 13:50:48 iPad-minQA SpringBoard[58] <Warning>: Reply Error: Connection interrupted
Jan  1 13:50:48 iPad-minQA afcd[255] <Error>: valid 0 value 0
Jan  1 13:50:49 iPad-minQA corecaptured[293] <Warning>: CCXPCService::setStreamEventHandler Woken up by notifyd.
Jan  1 13:50:49 iPad-minQA corecaptured[293] <Warning>: CCProfileMonitor::profileCallback Entered token:5
Jan  1 13:50:49 iPad-minQA wirelessproxd[59] <Warning>: Leaking old log directory path because it was set after logging has begun: /var/mobile/Library/Logs/Bluetooth for facilities: (null)
Jan  1 13:50:49 iPad-minQA SpringBoard[58] <Warning>: |GAXGeneral|info| whitelistedApps and appSelfLockIDs both nil.  No need to enable GAX (Single App Mode)
Jan  1 13:50:49 iPad-minQA assertiond[67] <Error>: assertion failed: 13G35: assertiond + 30600 [0B862A7D-6E8B-3778-AD17-C7694ECD5BCD]: 0x16
Jan  1 13:50:49 iPad-minQA tccd[106] <Notice>: Refusing client without bundle identifier (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/Support/medialibraryd)
Jan  1 13:50:49 iPad-minQA tccd[106] <Notice>: Refusing client without bundle identifier (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/Support/medialibraryd)
Jan  1 13:50:50 iPad-minQA Preferences[272] <Warning>: /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/ExternalAccessory/ExternalAccessory-329.40.4/EAAccessoryManager.m:__51-[EAAccessoryManager _checkForConnectedAccessories]_block_invoke-632 ending background task
Jan  1 13:52:23 iPad-minQA corecaptured[293] <Warning>: CCProfileMonitor::freeResources done
Jan  1 13:52:23 iPad-minQA corecaptured[293] <Warning>: Got an XPC error: Connection invalid
Jan  1 13:52:23 iPad-minQA corecaptured[293] <Warning>: CCLogTap::profileRemoved, Owner: com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANCore0, Name: DriverLogs
Jan  1 13:52:23 iPad-minQA corecaptured[293] <Warning>: CCLogTap::profileRemoved, Owner: com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANCore0, Name: FirmwareBusLogs
Jan  1 13:52:23 iPad-minQA corecaptured[293] <Warning>: CCLogTap::profileRemoved, Owner: com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANCore0, Name: DatapathEvents
Jan  1 13:57:46 iPad-minQA timed[62] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Received time 01/01/2017 11:57:46±0.03 from "NTP"
Jan  1 13:57:46 iPad-minQA timed[62] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Want active time in 20.41min. Need active time in 8312.08min. Remaining retry interval: 14.995156min.
Jan  1 13:57:46 iPad-minQA UserEventAgent[26] <Error>: validateAndAddDefaults(com.apple.timed): End Time (inf) > now (504964666.7) + BACKGROUND_TASK_AGENT_JOB_WINDOW_MAX_TIME_FROM_NOW_SEC (3024000.0) + BACKGROUND_TASK_AGENT_JOB_TIME_ERROR_MARGIN (300.0)
Jan  1 13:57:46 iPad-minQA timed[62] <Notice>: (Error) CoreTime: Error requesting proactive time check job
Jan  1 14:00:07 iPad-minQA syslogd[25] <Notice>: ASL Sender Statistics
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to make it work eventually.. the main problem was that apple configurator 2 was missing mandatory fields that are needed for the MDM profile to be installed.

I have added here a minimal profile example that needs to be generated for successful installation (make sure you have all the fields from below in your .mobileconfig file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PayloadContent</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>AccessRights</key>
            <integer>8191</integer>
            <key>CheckInURL</key>
            <string>https://192.168.0.12:8081/checkin</string>
            <key>CheckOutWhenRemoved</key>
            <false/>
            <key>IdentityCertificateUUID</key>
            <string>{IdentityCertificateUUID}</string>
            <key>PayloadDescription</key>
            <string>Configures Mobile Device Management</string>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>Mobile Device Management</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.mgmt.External.{PUSH_GUID}.mdm</string>
            <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
            <string>bla bla</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.mdm</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>{PayloadUUID}</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>ServerURL</key>
            <string>https://192.168.0.12:8081/server</string>
            <key>SignMessage</key>
            <true/>
            <key>Topic</key>
            <string>com.apple.mgmt.External.{PUSH_GUID}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Password</key>
            <string>{password}</string>
            <key>PayloadCertificateFileName</key>
            <string>Identity.p12</string>
            <key>PayloadContent</key>
            <data>
            {certificate data}
            </data>
            <key>PayloadDescription</key>
            <string>Adds a PKCS#12-formatted certificate</string>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>Identity.p12</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.mgmt.External.{PUSH_GUID}.credential</string>
            <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
            <string>{PayloadOrganization}</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.security.pkcs12</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>{PayloadUUID}</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>PayloadDescription</key>
    <string>Security managment profile installation.</string>
    <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
    <string>BLA BLA</string>
    <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.mgmt.External.{PUSH_GUID}</string>
    <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
    <string>BLA BLA</string>
    <key>PayloadRemovalDisallowed</key>
    <false/>
    <key>PayloadType</key>
    <string>Configuration</string>
    <key>PayloadUUID</key>
    <string>{PayloadUUID}</string>
    <key>PayloadVersion</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```